# Moving integers defined in .data section to registers

Tags: assembly, nasm, dos, x86-16, dosbox

I'm trying to initialize a memory location with a 16 bit integer and print it.

The result I get is the max value of an unsigned short. The size of *val* is `DW` so it's 16 bits, `AX` is 16 bits as well, so there is no size conflict.

`mov [val], word 122` does what I want, but if initialization in the main procedure was my goal, I would use `.bss` and *val2*.

Why is this happening and how do I actually get the value stored at *val*?

I use `nasm prog.asm -o prog.exe` under DOSBox.

```
section .data
    val dw 123

section .bss
    val2 resw 1

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; mov [val], word 122
    mov ax, word [val]
    mov cx, 0
    mov bx, 10

    loophere:
        mov dx, 0
        div bx                         

        push ax
        add dl, '0'                     

        pop ax                          
        push dx                         
        inc cx                          
        cmp ax, 0                       
        jnz loophere

    mov ah, 2    

    loophere2:
        pop dx                          
        int 21h                         
        loop loophere2
```

Comment: How do you assemble and link your binary?  Please post the exact commands and tools you use.  I am a bit confused about your code.  It doesn't show anything defined in the `.data` section.

Comment: Adding `org 0x100` at the top and assembling with `nasm -f bin -o foo.com foo.asm`, it correctly prints `123`, though of course it crashes after that when it runs off the end of the code.

Comment: If you are creating an `exe` file, you need to load the `ds` segment yourself.

Comment: As @NateEldredge said, you need to set an origin with the `org` directive.  Right now, all your offsets are off by `0x100` due to the wrong origin.

Comment: @fuz It's possible to produce executable code using nasm without a linker using the precise command line OP provided.  In this case OP is creating a .com file (although he named it .exe) which was something 16bit DOS supported.  It's [also possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65434734/2189500) to create actual exe files, even ones that have imports, solely using nasm to produce the output image.  Cool.  Not especially practical, but cool.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Yes it is.  I just wanted to make sure that this is what OP was doing.  In this case, adding `org 0x100` fixes OPs problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `org 0x100` at the beginning of the program solves the problem caused by a bad offset.

Comment: Note you will be creating a `.com` file this way, you should probably name the output accordingly.

Comment: @SepRoland: Sounds perfectly informative to me.  Did you really mean that just adding `org 0x100` as a new first line wouldn't be sufficient?  Like do you need to put the .text first because execution will enter at the top of the flat binary?  Or did you just mean that it doesn't explain why it's needed (because this is making a .com executable not .exe)?  Anyway, surely we have a duplicate for missing org 0x100 somewhere.

Comment: @SepRoland: Ok yeah, I can agree with that for sure.  Using sections in a `.com` did always seem super sketchy and like missing the point, except maybe as a way to get a "BSS" uninitialized space past the end of the .com.