# How can I run a Windows shell command in an assembly program, without needing a C library?

Tags: windows, assembly, cmd, mingw, masm

I'm learning assembly, but I've been learning on Linux, and it's been very interwoven with C/C++ since I understand C/C++.

However, now, I want to write a program in assembly on my Windows computer that makes a call to a function that runs a shell command, and hopefully without including any libraries since I want this executable to be **as small as possible**. (A simple C++ executable I made which included `cstdlib` is 32 KB while I typed barely any code at all.)

I want to essentially write this program but in assembly:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    system("echo ABCDEFG> msg.txt");
    system("type msg.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

So far, I have installed NASM and MinGW and I'm trying to use them [Edit: I am now trying to use MASM instead, with Visual Studio], but nothing works and I assume it's because Windows has its own stuff from Microsoft that obviously aren't in Linux, but none of the online resources I've come across have successfully compiled with what I was trying to do. It also doesn't seem to understand the statement `extern system`, so I think that this might be a C/C++ library thing (from `cstdlib`).

Also, in some cases I encountered an error where it said the "character constant is too long". I assume it's referring to the string; in the real program, the string to echo is much longer than what's in the example above.

I also had an issue apparently with the .obj file that was generated.

So, basically, all I need is how to turn the above program into assembly for Windows, and how to get NASM and MinGW to turn it into an executable without giving me errors.

Edit: After a few days of researching, I have decided I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I can't figure out what is right.

I've tried Visual Studio now, but once again, it doesn't understand `extern system`.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.data
    Var db  'dir && pause', 0

.code
extern system

main PROC
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 32
    lea     ecx, [Var]
    call    system
    xor     eax, eax
    INVOKE  ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: I think you're looking for the `CreateProcess` WinAPI function.  But if you want actual shell processing like `>` redirects, you might need to build a command line for `cmd` or feed it a batch file.  CreateProcess would just pass along a flat string as args (unlike POSIX, it is just a flat string, not an array of args, so it's up to each process to tokenize its incoming arg string, applying whatever choice of quoting rules it wants...  This design seems obviously inferior to POSIX `execve`, separately from `cmd` being a worse shell than `bash` or `zsh`, at least if you're used to bash.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Well, I agree that cmd sucks compared to bash, and I do have bash experience. I see what you're going after, but as of right now, the commands being passed along are constants and it doesn't need to be interactive. Just double-click and it runs the commands stored as a constant within the program. I was hoping for a program that would be something like the x86-64 gcc C++ output, which is .LC0: .string "(command)" main: push rbp mov rbp, rsp mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0 call system mov eax, 0 pop rbp ret. My main goal in this is to make an executable as small as possible, thus asm.

Comment: Pretty sure user-space needs to at least tokenize the command separately from the rest of the string to know what executable to start. Like the system() library function (not system call). Windows systems do normally have a msvcrt C library DLL, though, so assuming there's a `system()` or similar function in there, you can just link against that if you're mostly concerned about your own executable being as small as possible, rather than doing it manually in asm. IDK Windows very well, though. Still, needing to process redirects means you probably can't just pass an arg to a WinAPI func.

Comment: (reposted previous comment due to assume / assuming typo.  I'm not sure if msvcrt would have a function like `system`.)

Comment: MSVC [does have](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=msvc-170) a system command.  I'm more interested in "have successfully compiled."  What errors do you get?  Perhaps you're simply missing a library?  If size is really that important, there are [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65434734/2189500) that might let you trim things down a bit more.  Seems like more work than it's worth though.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I've since found some that have worked, but they do other things like display text. I'm trying to invoke the console or something like that so I can run shell commands saved as constants from an executable written in assembly.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've since updated my code. The errors are "line 10: syntax error: in directive" and "line 17: undefined symbol: System". So I guess trying to get the system function from somewhere didn't work because I did it wrong. Also, if you would happen to know where I can view the implementation of the system function in C++, from cstdlib, that would be helpful. I can't seem to find it, just the declaration itself.

Comment: That's not [nasm] code; you should probably fix the tags on your question if you're now using MASM.  `extern system` is a valid NASM directive.  (Of course it won't avoid linker errors if the library doesn't define that symbol!).  I don't know the MASM equivalent, and DLL imports are normally different because you need to make an indirect call anyway.  As for where to find an implementation of `system()`, I wouldn't know where to start looking for Windows, if there even is one in the library.  For Linux I'd look in the glibc source code, but that's not helpful at all for Windows.

Comment: "shell commands saved as constants" I'm not sure I follow.  You want to create an run a batch file?  If you create foo.cmd, you should be able to run it with `system("foo.cmd");`.  Alternately, something like "foo.exe && bar.exe && boo.exe" would be a valid shell command.  As for *undefined symbol: System*, I'd start by making it lower case.  And what libraries are you linking in?  Looks like the function is in msvcrt.dll (among other places), so presumably msvcrt.lib would be a place to start.

Comment: @PeterCordes Good point, I was originally using NASM but I am now using MASM. I will fix this.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Technically yes, this could be done as a batch file, but I wanted to see if it is possible to do this as a one-liner with a string. The real command, which I'm not going to post here, is long for a one-liner, but I've seen longer ones. My goal is to have everything in a single executable; and while I could write the whole program along with the parts I've left out from this post in C or C++, my goal is to make the executable as small as possible; 32 KB isn't going to cut it. Ideally (hypothetically) all that's needed is what's required for system() and the bytes of my text.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, Windows does have a [system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=msvc-170) command.  It's located in MSVCRT.dll, so you'll need to link with msvcrt.lib to resolve the external reference.

The error you are getting from "line 11" is due to incorrectly defining the external, which is odd since you're correctly doing the same for ExitProcess (which is also an external) just a few lines before.

32k may sound big, but Windows works in 4k pages these days, allowing it set [page protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-protection-constants) bits (read-only pages, executable pages, etc).  One page for executable code, one for data, one for constants, imports, exports, debug info, exception info, etc.  8 pages doesn't seem that outrageous by today's standards.

But as I also mentioned, there are [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65434734/2189500) one can use to reduce the size of the executable if there's some compelling reason to do so.  This sample (built with NASM version 2.15.05 using `nasm.exe doit.asm -o doit.exe`) is 1,184 bytes.  When you run it, nothing seems to happen (no cmd window opens) and it's really quick.  But you'll see that foo.xxx gets created and contains the output from the `dir > foo.xxx` command embedded in the code.

There's a lot of gobbledygook here that the linker normally handles for you.  The interesting bits start at `ENTRY:`.  cmd is defined near the end of the code.

The stealthy nature of this code combined with the small size opens the possibility of using this code for mischief.  I'm going to assume that's not your intent.

```
; Check for NASM version at least 2.15.05
%if __?NASM_VERSION_ID?__ < 0x0020F0500
%error "Newer version of nasm required"
%endif

%define RoundTo(a, b) ((((a) + ((b) - 1)) / (b)) * (b))
%define Stringify(&val) val

%macro NameEntry 2
%1__  dw %2
db Stringify(%1), 0
%endmacro

salign    equ 1000h   ; Page size in memory
falign    equ 200h    ; Page size in file
imageBase equ 400000h ; Requested load address

BITS 16

section headers start=0
startoffile:

    ; MZ header https://wiki.osdev.org/MZ
    dw  "MZ"                        ; Signature
    dw (dosBlkSize - mzStructSize) % 512  ; Bytes on last page
    dw RoundTo(dosBlkSize, 512) / 512     ; # of 512 byte pages
    dw 0                            ; Relocation items
    dw RoundTo(mzStructSize, 16) / 16 ; Header size in paragraphs
    dw 0                            ; Minimum allocation
    dw 0xffff                       ; Maximum allocation in paragraphs (1M).
    dw 0                            ; Initial SS
    dw 0xb8                         ; Initial SP
    dw 0                            ; Checksum
    dw 0                            ; Initial IP
    dw 0                            ; Initial CS
    dw 0                            ; Relocation table
    dw 0                            ; Overlay
    dq 0                            ; Reserved
    dw 0                            ; OEM identifier
    dw 0                            ; OEM info
    times 20 db 0                   ; Reserved
    dd PEHDR                        ; PE header start

mzStructSize  equ $ - $$ ; aka 64

dosstartcode:   ; Print the error and exit
    push cs
    pop  ds
    mov  dx, dosmsg - dosstartcode
    mov  ah, 0x9
    int  0x21       ; Show string up to '$'
    mov  ax, 4c01h
    int  0x21       ; Exit process with error code 1

    dosmsg db `This program cannot be run in DOS mode.\r\r\n$`

dosBlkSize  equ $ - $$

ALIGN 16

; From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format
PEHDR:
    dd  "PE"            ; signature
    dw  8664h           ; machine x64
    dw  SectionsCount   ; # of sections
    dd  __POSIX_TIME__  ; timedatestamp
    dd  0               ; pointer to symtab - deprecated
    dd  0               ; # symtab entries
    dw  opthdrSize      ; size of optional header
    dw  2h              ; flags: Executable
       
OPTHDR:
    dw  20Bh            ; magic
    db  0               ; maj linker ver
    db  0               ; minor linker ver
    dd  codeSizeS       ; total memory code size
    dd  rdataSizeS      ; total memory init data size
    dd  0               ; total uninit data size
    dd  ENTRY           ; entrypoint RVA   
    dd  section..text.start ; base of code in file
    dq  imageBase       ; image base
    dd  salign          ; section address alignment
    dd  falign          ; section pos alignment
    dw  10              ; major OS version
    dw  0               ; minor OS version
    dw  0               ; major image ver
    dw  1               ; minor image ver
    dw  6               ; major subsystem ver
    dw  2               ; minor subsystem ver
    dd  0               ; win32 version value = 0
    dd  fileSize        ; size of image in memory
    dd  headersSizeF    ; size of DOS stub + PE header + sections
    dd  0               ; checksum
    dw  2               ; subsystem: GUI
    dw  8160h           ; dll characteristics: HighEntropy, Relocatable, NX, TS aware
    dq  100h            ; max stack
    dq  100h            ; min stack
    dq  100h            ; max heap
    dq  100h            ; min heap
    dd  0               ; loader flag

HeaderDirectories:
    dd  HeaderDirectoryCount   ; number of directories
       
    ; Address, Size
    dd  0, 0                        ; Export
    dd ImportsDir, ImportsDirSize   ; Import
    dd 0, 0                         ; Resource
    dd 0, 0                         ; Exception
    dd 0, 0                         ; Certificates
    dd 0, 0                         ; Base Relocation
    dd 0, 0                         ; Debug
    dd 0, 0                         ; Architecture
    dd 0, 0                         ; Global Pointer
    dd 0, 0                         ; Thread Storage
    dd 0, 0                         ; Load Configuration
    dd 0, 0                         ; Bound Import
    dd IATStart, IATSize            ; Import Address Table
    dd 0, 0                         ; Delay Import
    dd 0, 0                         ; COM Descriptor
    dd 0, 0                         ; Reserved

HeaderDirectorySize equ $ - HeaderDirectories
HeaderDirectoryCount equ HeaderDirectorySize / 8

opthdrSize  equ $ - OPTHDR

startOfSections:

    dq  ".text"
    dd  codeSizeS           ; size in memory pages
    dd  ENTRY               ; addr RVA (memory offset)
    dd  codeSize            ; length
    dd  section..text.start ; pos (file offset)
    dd  0           ; relocations addr
    dd  0           ; linenum addr
    dw  0           ; relocations count
    dw  0           ; linenum count
    dd  030000020h  ; flags: Code, Shared, Execute Only

    dq  ".rdata"
    dd  rdataSizeS              ; size in memory pages
    dd  RDATA                   ; addr RVA (memory offset)
    dd  rdataSize               ; length
    dd  section.rdata.start     ; pos (file offset)
    dd  0           ; relocations addr
    dd  0           ; linenum addr
    dw  0           ; relocations count
    dw  0           ; linenum count

    ; Take advantage of the fact that the loader cheats and 
    ; writes imports to readonly pages @ startup
    dd  040000040h  ; flags: Initialized Data, Read Only

SectionsSize equ $ - startOfSections
SectionsCount equ SectionsSize / 40
   
ALIGN 16
headersSizeF equ RoundTo($ - $$, falign)
headersSizeS equ RoundTo($ - $$, salign)

BITS 64

DEFAULT REL ; so we don't have to keep adding imageBase

SECTION .text vstart=headersSizeS align=falign follows=headers

    ENTRY: 
        sub rsp, 28h 
        lea rcx, [cmd]    ; LPCSTR lpCmd
        call [system]

        ; Use the return value from the call to system
        mov ecx, eax
        call [ExitProcess]

codeSize   equ $ - $$
codeSizeS  equ RoundTo(codeSize, salign)

SECTION rdata vstart=headersSizeS+codeSizeS align=falign

RDATA:

IATStart:

; Import Address Table
Kernel32TableA:
    ExitProcess    dq ExitProcess__

MSVCRTTableA:
    system    dq system__

IATSize equ $ - IATStart

ImportsDir:
    dd  Kernel32TableL, 0, 0, kernel32dll, Kernel32TableA
    dd  MSVCRTTableL, 0, 0, MSVCRTdll, MSVCRTTableA

ImportsDirSize   equ $ - ImportsDir

; Kernel32 Import Lookup Table
Kernel32TableL:
    dq ExitProcess__
    dq 0 ; end of table marker

; Name, Hint
NameEntry ExitProcess, 164h

; MSVCRT Import Lookup Table
MSVCRTTableL:
    dq system__
    dq 0 ; end of table marker

; Name, Hint
NameEntry system, 4e0h

kernel32dll   db  "KERNEL32.dll", 0
MSVCRTdll     db  "MSVCRT.dll", 0

; Constant data
cmd     db  "dir > foo.xxx", 0h

ALIGN 16
rdataSize equ $ - RDATA
rdataSizeS equ RoundTo(rdataSize, salign)

fileSize equ RDATA + rdataSizeS
```

Answer (score 0):

You usage of extern does not make any sense, extern in masm means you are calling an API function (like printf in c) not a executable file.  The first comment is correct.  In the win32 api a process launched from anther process you need the CreateProcessA or CreateProcessW function and you need to setup a PROCESS_INFORMATION structure to pass it.  You might have to set up other structures too, I don't remember, then you call it if you pushed to arguments to the stack manually or simply invoke it and let the assembler handle that.  I would recommend getting a copy of masm32, that should make it easy, there is likely already a sample in it or on the internet.

Comment: Opps I didn't know SYSTEM was a function in MSVCRT.dll, the answer above mine is helpful correct, but if you are getting into win32 asm masm32 is not bad, nor fasm.