# Understanding SizeOfHeaders

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm, portable-executable, file-format

Learning some nasm, and file formats for my assembly project. I am currently very confused about `SizeOfHeaders`.

Taking a look at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms809762(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> The size of the PE header and the section (object) table. The raw data for the sections starts immediately after all the header components.

Taking a look at another [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_optional_header32):

> The combined size of the following items, rounded to a multiple of the value specified in the FileAlignment member.
>
> - **`e_lfanew`** member of **`IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`**
> - 4 byte signature
> - size of `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER`
> - size of optional header
> - size of all section headers

Other sources online say:

> The combined size of an MS‑DOS stub, PE header, and section headers rounded up to a multiple of FileAlignment.

As you can see each source is giving a different explanation of what is comprised of SizeOfHeaders.

In NASM, the SizeOfHeaders could be computed as such:

```
dd sections_start - dos_stub_start + (FileAlignment - 1)) // FileAlignment
```

That would be the example of the implementation of simplest source, and one that I have used, however the second official source that I listed, specifically says the e_lfanew member of the dos header, not the whole dos stub or not any of the dos header or stub at all for the first source.

So that example may very well be incorrect.

Looking online, there doesn't seem to be any conclusive information previously recorded on the internet about this issue.

Comment: I can't remember the answer off the top of my head. My suggestion would be to look for a PE dump utility. For traditional reasons I personally use TDump that comes with Borland/Embarcadero dev tools, but I believe there's one from Microsoft too, and no doubt others as well.

Comment: [Last time I played with this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65434734/2189500), I tried to use computed sizes (rather than hardcoded values) and cite my sources.  FWIW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I calculate value of the member **SizeOfHeaders** in IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER:

PE executable file begins with **DOS_HEADER** (size 64), followed by MZ executable 16bit DOS **stub** file, which may have variable size.

**DOS_HEADER.e_lfanew** (the last DWORD) specifies file address (offset) of PE, LE or NE **signature** in the executable file.
Adding the signature size (4) to e_lfanew value gives the offset of **IMAGE_FILE_HEADER**. Size of this file header is fixed (20).

File header is followed by **IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER** with size 224 or 240 bytes for 32bit or 64bit versions.

Member **IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.NumberOfSections** specifies how many IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER instances follow the optional header. Each section header is 40 bytes long.
Adding it all together and rounding it up to **IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.FileAlignment** (usually 512) gives the final value of
**IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.SizeOfHeaders**.

A good GUI tool for inspection of 32bit COFF and PE files is [PEview](http://wjradburn.com/software/) by W.J.Radburn.

Comment: What about the COFF header?

Comment: @J.Doe  Linkable COFF object file begins with [COFF File Header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#coff-file-header-object-and-image) (20 bytes) followed with one [COFF Section Header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#section-table-section-headers) (40 bytes) for each section (.text, .data etc) and then follows the raw emited contents of sections, and, finally, [COFF Symbol Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#coff-symbol-table) (18 bytes each symbol).