# link.exe unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup

Tags: assembly, x86, linker, nasm, linker-errors

All I want to do is get a simple `.exe` that does nothing without any external libraries. I have the simplest nasm program in the world:

```
global main
section .text
main:
    nop
```

I compile it like this:

```
nasm -f coff -o program.o program.asm
```

Then, when I try to link it with `LINK.EXE`, it results in the following error:

```
link program.o
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30154.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
program.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Why is it doing this?!? I'm not referencing anything called `_mainCRTStartup`

Also, this code compiled succesfuly earlier. Then, afeter trying to link a windows program, it started failing.

Comment: If you aren't trying to make a Windows program, what are you trying to make?

Comment: Possibly you were trying to do something where you want to pass these options to the linker? `/subsystem:console /entry:main`

Comment: If you're trying to get really low level, nasm doesn't actually require the linker: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65434734/2189500  It may look longer than a simple `nop`, but the linker is adding all that stuff to the executable anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @michaelpetch I just want a basic program that does nothing (for now, until I can at least compile it)

Comment: If I add the option `/subsystem:console` and `/nodefaultlib` while linking then it fails with `LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __main`

Comment: `__main` seems like something from MinGW. Are you issuing other commands to assemble and link you are not showing. With your original code (that just does the NOP) did you ever just try what I suggested at first. Do: `nasm -f coff -o program.o program.asm` `and then link /subsystem:console /entry:main program.o`. When you run it, it should crash since there is no exit back to the OS after the `NOP`. You could try putting a `ret` after the `NOP`.

Comment: I'm just compiling with `nasm -f coff -o program.o program.asm` and linking with `link /subsystem:console /entry:main program.o` and it has the `__main` error